# Cassandra access control

Tags: authentication, cassandra

Is there any way to restrict access to Cassandra? 
In mysql users require a username and password before access can be gained, including tools such as workbench. Is there any such system in place or can the CLI and cqlsh tools access Cassandra regardless?

Answer (score 4):

Which version of Cassandra are you using?  For 1.2.2 and later, you can authenticate using the PasswordAuthenticator and CassandraAuthorizer as described in the documentation (http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.2/security/native_authentication):

> 1- Change the cassandra.yaml authenticator setting to
>   PasswordAuthenticator:
>
> `authenticator: org.apache.cassandra.auth.PasswordAuthenticator`

You will also want to set the auhorizer to CassandraAuthorizer:

> `authorizer: com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.CassandraAuthorizer`
>
> 2- [Configure the replication factor for the `system_auth` keyspace](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.2/security/security_keyspace_replication#security-keyspace-replication).
>
> 3- Restart Cassandra.
>
> A default superuser name and password (cassandra) that you use to
>   start the supported client is stored in Cassandra. For example, to
>   start cqlsh:
>
> `./cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra`
>
> You can now set up user accounts and
>   authorize users to access the database objects by using CQL to grant
>   them permissions on those objects.

Of course, you will want to read the information (in the above link) on how to "Change the superuser password."

Once you've done that, cassandra-cli can be invoked to how cqlsh was in the above example:

```
./cassandra-cli -u username -pw password
```

For an overview, you should also check-out the doc: [A Quick Tour of Internal Authentication and Authorization Security in DataStax Enterprise and Apache Cassandra](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/a-quick-tour-of-internal-authentication-and-authorization-security-in-datastax-enterprise-and-apache-cassandra)

Answer (score 2):

**It is the [only resource](http://planetca.w11.wh-2.com/blog/post/announcing-datastax-community-edition-with-apache-cassandra-122) I have found that is related to Authentication:**

> With version 1.2.2, we’ve delivered internal authentication and
>   authorization that lets you manage login ID’s and passwords inside of
>   Cassandra, as well as who can do what inside a database cluster from
>   an authorization (i.e. permissions) perspective.

**Going around, this took me to: DataStax Enterprise 3.0 Documentation [Security management](http://www.datastax.com/docs/datastax_enterprise3.0/security/security_features#security_features) section on http://www.datastax.com/docs**

> DataStax Enterprise 3.0 includes a number of features for securing
>   data. The security framework provides advanced data protection for
>   enterprise-grade databases. You can secure a DataStax Community or
>   DataStax Enterprise cluster using these features.
>
> Internal authentication using login accounts and passwords
>   Object permission management based on the GRANT/REVOKE paradigm
>   Client to node encryption using SSL for data going from the client to the Cassandra cluster
>
> DataStax Enterprise offers additional security, not included in
>   DataStax Community, to enterprises for mission-critical data:
>
> Kerberos authentication: a network authentication protocol that allow nodes communicating over a non-secure network to prove their
>   identity to one another in a secure manner using tickets. You can also
>   set up Kerberos to use LDAP for authentication.
>
> Transparent data encryption: the encoding of data flushed from the memtable in system memory to the SSTables on disk (at rest data) to be
>   unreadable to unauthorized users. Encryption and decryption occurs
>   without user intervention.
>
> Data auditing: the administrator capability to create detailed audit trails of cluster activity.

**By the way, [DataStax Community – Comparative of DataStax Enterprise Edition and DataStax Community Edition](http://www.datastax.com/products/community/compare) says:**

> DataStax Community Edition: Contains the latest version of the
>   Cassandra database for real-time data management, plus a free version
>   of DataStax OpsCenter. Not supported for production systems.

**Including for DataStax Community Edition:**

> Security Features     General security features

**Instead than DataStax Enterprise that mentions:**

> Security Features General and advanced security features

**In conclusion, take a look, security capacities were implemented since 1.2.2 version and maybe you have not to pay at all depending of security parts that you are requiring.**

**Other Reference:
[Apache Cassandra 1.2 Documentation - Security section](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.2/security/index) that contains resources about:**

- [Configuring and using internal authentication](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.2/security/native_authentication)
- [Managing object permissions using internal authorization](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.2/security/native_authorization)